# Нужно, чтобы иконки выглядели одинаково ровно

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Мне нужно, чтобы иконки выглядели так, как на скриншоте:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался добиться этого при помощи `border-radius`и `padding`, но судя по всему, делаю что-то не так (так как выходит криво).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ещё отдельная картинка-эллипс (возможно, при помощи неё получится добиться):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="vk-icon.png" alt="">
        <img src="facebook-icon.png" alt="">
        <img src="instagram-icon.png" alt="">
    </div>
</body>
</html>


* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background-color: #000;
}
.container {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.container img {
    margin-right: 60px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Пропиши класс для всех img и задай в нем нужную тебе ширину и высоту, можешь в процентном соотношении от размера контейнера.

Comment: а вы для иконок не используйте img а используйте шрифтовые иконки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю использовать шрифтовые иконки

Сморите дэмо

```css
body{
  text-align: center;
}
i.fa{
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

i.fa-facebook{
  margin: 0 30px;
}

i.fa:hover{
color: blue;

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<i class="fa fa-vk"></i>
<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
<i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
```

Comment: У меня по-своему, но Ваше решение с шрифтовыми иконками помогло. Благодарю!

Answer (score 2):

А так? Проверяйте

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 60px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  -ms-border-radius: 25px;
  -o-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="vk-icon.png" alt="">
  <img src="facebook-icon.png" alt="">
  <img src="instagram-icon.png" alt="">
</div>
```